# Android x86 (Android 6.0) is locked at the android animation after booting (VirtualBox)

Tags: virtualbox, linux-mint, android-x86

So, using VirtualBox, I wanted to install Android x86 9.0 on my virtual machine. Following this [guide](https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/virtualbox.html), I've succesfully made it. However, after booting from the GRUB, it stays on the android animation thing. Having a weak ram, I hoped it was because 9.0 needed more power my PC was able to give. So I did it with Android x86 6.0. I made the same installation and all, then when it showed the android animation, I let my PC ran all over the night (during 10 hours so). When I powered on my monitor, it was locked on the same screen. I'm now stuck on this screen, and I don't know what to do to finally start my Android 6.0.
I've already made some searches, but all I could find was some answers to display errors, which I have not (I guess).

Here is my PC details :

```
                                       *****@********
 MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMmds+.        OS: Mint 19.3 tricia
 MMm----::-://////////////oymNMd+`     Kernel: i686 Linux 5.4.0-73-generic
 MMd      /++                -sNMd:    Uptime: 23h 30m
 MMNso/`  dMM    `.::-. .-::.` .hMN:   Packages: 3656
 ddddMMh  dMM   :hNMNMNhNMNMNh: `NMm   Shell: bash 4.4.20
     NMm  dMM  .NMN/-+MMM+-/NMN` dMM   Resolution: 1440x900
     NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   DE: XFCE
     NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   WM: Metacity
     NMm  dMM  .mmd  `mmm   yMM. dMM   GTK Theme: Mint-Y-Dark-Grey [GTK2]
     NMm  dMM`  ..`   ...   ydm. dMM   Icon Theme: Mint-Y-Dark-Grey
     hMM- +MMd/-------...-:sdds  dMM   Font: Ubuntu 10
     -NMm- :hNMNNNmdddddddddy/`  dMM   CPU: Intel Pentium D 3.00GHz @ 2x 2.992GHz
      -dMNs-``-::::-------.``    dMM   GPU: ATI RC410
       `/dMNmy+/:-------------:/yMMM   RAM: 1317MiB / 1753MiB
          ./ydNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM  
             \.MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

Here is my virtual machine details (this is in French): [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmO3Q.png)

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

hello use vmware workstation for run androidx86